# Vectorizing a raster zone map without the lines turning into squares QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, line, pixel, vectorization

Raster zone lines turn into squares after vectorizing my raster because of pixels between color zones QGIS [image]

[image]

Comment: i've tried generalizer plugin, sieve tool and many others. Can not get those squares to just be a vector line

Comment: They have different raster values? Is is possible to reclass the raster to fewer unique values? Your raster is one band or 3?

Comment: the raster is actually just a kmz file from google earth because thats how i give it a location. It just has 1 band i believe. I need to define the raster somehow or smooth it before i vectorize